# cmd window is not disappered c#

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm trying to opening a program from different user using cmd window (is not exe file so I have to open it from there), the program is start, but the cmd open is still appear (altough I did `CreateNoWindow=true`).

Code:

```
    var p = new process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/C C:Windows\System32\theprogram")
    {
       Domain = mydomain, 
       Username = myusername,
       password = securepass,
       UseShellExecute = false,
       CreateNoWindow = true,
       WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\"
    };
    p.Start();
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I tried already but it didn't works

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Hi, thanks. but it still doesn't work. It happens only when I'm adding username, password and domain properties. Without them, my code is working perfect...